# Compilation error when a command argument contains a math formula with a bracket ]

Tags: math-mode, errors, brackets

When I try to compile the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{modelDefinitions}{%
  \begin{description}
}{%
  \end{description}
}
\newcommand{\modelDef}[2]{\item[#1] \hfill \\ #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{modelDefinitions}
  \modelDef{$test[a, b]$}{tmp}
\end{modelDefinitions}
\end{document}
```

I get a compilation error saying:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\sbox ...hbox {\color@setgroup #2\color@endgroup }

l.12   \modelDef{$test[a, b]$}{tmp}
```

However, if I remove the `]` from the first argument of `\modelDef`, then it works. What's the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: TeX isn't as good at matching square brackets `[` as it is at matching curly braces `{`. You best bet might be to define a macro `\def\foo{[a,b]}` and then do `\modelDef{$test\foo$}…`

Comment: Don't write `test` in mathmode, because it is taken as a product of four variables. Use at least `\mathrm{test}` or `\mathit{test}`.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: I know - just didn't bother since this was an example. But thanks anyway. =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem arises due to instant grabbing of the entire `[]` part in `\item`. In your case it will grab `$test[a, b` as the argument, leaving you with an unfinished `$` and a floating `$` afterwards. Thus you need to tell `LaTeX` what belongs where.

You can circumvent this issue by adding a group like this

```
\newcommand{\modelDef}[2]{\item[{#1}] \hfill \\ #2}
```

Then it will not complain.